# Error: Connection terminated - ASYNC nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, api

How to end my async connection when all data is entered correctly?

Even declaring the end of the connection outside the loop, the structure is being finalized after the first INSERT

**CODE**

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');
let queryAPI = {
    "query": `{
                squads {
                    name
                        cards(includedOnKanban: true, closed: false, archived: false, cancelled: false, swimlaneName:\"Atividades Nao Transacionais\", updatedSince: \"2020-01-01T00:00:00-0300\") {
                            identifier
                            title
                            description
                            status
                            priority
                            assignees {
                                fullname
                                email
                              }
                              swimlane
                              workstate
                        }
                    }
            }`
};
(async () => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch('https://www.bluesight.io/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Bluesight-API-Token': 'token-here'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(queryAPI)
  });
  const content = await rawResponse.json();
  const { Client } = require('pg');
  const client = new Client({
      user: 'postgres',
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      database: 'postgres',
      password: 'postgres',
      port: 5432
  })
  client.connect();

  const query = `INSERT INTO tb_bluesight 
       (identifier,title,description,status,priority,date_insert) 
       VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, current_timestamp)`;
  var data = Object.keys(content);
  var squads = Object.keys(content[data]);
  var cards = Object.keys(content[data][squads][0]['cards']);

    try{
      for(x in cards){
        const parameters = [
          content[data]["squads"][0]["cards"][x]['identifier'],
          content[data]["squads"][0]["cards"][x]['title'],
          content[data]["squads"][0]["cards"][x]['description'],
          content[data]["squads"][0]["cards"][x]['status'],
          content[data]["squads"][0]["cards"][x]['priority']

        ];
        client.query(query, parameters, (err, res) => {

            console.log(err, res);

        })
      }
   }catch(e){
      console.log("undefined");

   }

client.end();

})();
```

**OUTPUT**

> Error: Connection terminated
>       at Connection. (C:\Users\TESTE\Documents\Autoportal\api\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:254:9)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)
>       at Connection.emit (events.js:323:22)

Comment: You need `await client.connect()` and `const res = await client.query()` to handle the asynchronicity of the `pg` package. Otherwise `client.end()` gets called before you get your work done.

Comment: Got it, it seems like a silly mistake, could I just show a code snippet fixing this problem? I couldn't understand how to replicate this in my code, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use  `await client.connect()`

and, for your queries, this

```
    res = await client.query(query, parameters);
```

in place of this

```
    client.query(query, parameters, (err, res) => {
        console.log(err, res);
    })
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'm no genius, I've just had many pains in my neck getting this sort of thing to work.

Comment: I imagine, I'm a beginner in nodeJS, I come from python, where everything works easy, I'm suffering a lot rs'